# Getting nested iframes with Facebooker in iframe app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, facebooker

Has anyone encountered nested iframes in their Rails/Facebooker application? 
Basically, every time I click an action or link, the entire facebook page reloads inside my existing iframe, causing two (and more on each subsequent click) facebook borders to appear.

I've gone over the instructions three times and changed every setting imaginable, but the app still opens up in new facebook page inside the iframe. Any ideas anyone?

itonly appears when I use the

```
ensure_application_is_installed_by_facebook_user
```

filter, but if the user already has the application installed and I use the

```
ensure_authenticated_to_facebook
```

filter, it works fine...very strange (to me at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out ensure_application_is_installed_by_facebook_user is deprecated because of a change in Facebook's API.
I plan to update the Facebooker documentation with this information soon.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing with nested iframes, so I used "ensure_authenticated_to_facebook" instead.  The only gotcha was that after the user installed the app, it would redirect them to my domain and not the facebook iframe page.  After doing some tweaking in facebooker, I decided to hard code :canvas=>"true" in this method which is in lib/facebooker/rails/controller.rb line 189

```
def create_new_facebook_session_and_redirect!
      session[:facebook_session] = new_facebook_session
      next_url = after_facebook_login_url || default_after_facebook_login_url
      #top_redirect_to session[:facebook_session].login_url({:next => next_url, :canvas=>params[:fb_sig_in_canvas]}) unless @installation_required
      top_redirect_to session[:facebook_session].login_url({:next => next_url, :canvas=>"true"}) unless @installation_required
      false
end
```

I wrote a tutorial on this fix in my blog - http://railsrant.com/2009/10/14/creating-a-facebook-iframe-app-using-ruby-on-rails-facebooker/