# Nested iframes in Rails/Facebooker app when using Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, facebooker, facebook-iframe

(I know there's been a similar question here: [Getting nested iframes with Facebooker in iframe app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474817/getting-nested-iframes-with-facebooker-in-iframe-app), but that fix didn't seem to work)

I'm currently developing a Facebook iframe app in Rails using the Facebooker plugin. However, I'm getting some weird cross-browser incompatibilities. The app works fine in Firefox and Chrome on my machine. In Internet Explorer, every time a link is clicked, the new frame appears inside the old one (so you get nested frames). On my friends machine, this also happens in Firefox. In Safari, I get a Rails error message.

I've tried various fixes, including a workaround with Javascript, but nothing seems to work.

More info: my app is at apps.facebook.com/chinesevillebeta/, and loads the page from www.chinese-ville.com. Oddly, when you visit www.chinese-ville.com, assuming you have a Facebook session open, IE redirects you to Facebook, where the app appears in an iframe. Firefox and Chrome, on the other hand, just show you the app by itself, no iframes. It seems like a really weird cross-browser incompatibility that I've not been able to find documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but could try adding target="_top" to your link tags